# How to pass parameters in Datatables function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to pass 1 parameter in my datatable function: `addfctCallback`

```
var buttons = [];
buttons.push({
  text: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> new',
  className: 'product-add btn btn-success btn-xs',
  titleAttr: 'add a product',
  action: addfctCallback  // how to pass the parameter here?
}
```

I want get the 'param' in my function addfctCallback :

```
function addfctCallback(e, param) {
  console.log('param : ' + param);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: In that case, add `return param` in function addfctCallback

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you spend some more time on your question? It is not clear enough as for me

Comment: add return param ?
function addfctCallback(e, param) {
  console.log('param : ' + param);
return  param;
} ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy pasta from the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/event/button-action)

```
action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    alert( 'Activated!' );
                    this.disable(); // disable button
                }
```

Comment: Added better link